# C++ SetConsoleCtrlHandler returns program to Main or not

Tags: c++, event-handling, console-application

I am trying to catch the event closing console window of a console application written in C++. From the other post I made last night and some google, I got down to using

```
BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent)
{
    char mesg[128];

    switch(CEvent)
    {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        Beep( 750, 300 ); 
        escape = 1;
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "CTRL+C received!","CEvent",MB_OK);
        break;
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        //MessageBox(NULL,
        //  "CTRL+BREAK received!","CEvent",MB_OK);
        break;
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        escape = 1;
        //MessageBox(NULL,
        //  "Program being closed!","CEvent",MB_OK);
        break;
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "User is logging off!","CEvent",MB_OK);
        break;
    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "User is logging off!","CEvent",MB_OK);
        break;

    }
    return FALSE;  // TRUE: process terminated; FALSE: process passed to next handler or if no else process is terminated
}
```

The original purpose of this event catching is to force the program to return to main and finish there after user click [x] to close console window.

It's interesting though the handler is always called but the program does not return to main sometimes, it's sometimes yes and others no. Especially, when I don't use "MessageBox" in event handler. It most likely not to return to main

Am I doing the right way to force the so-called program cursor to return to main?

Edit 01:

It's can be tested by putting a breakpoint at "return" keyword of main thread and the event handler which shows clear that event's "return" is reached everytime but never does for the main thread. And the output also shows the order of program exited:

```
The thread 'Main Thread' (0x1524) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5300] eventhandler.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

This raise another question I might put in another post
I also edit to show I put return in the handler

Comment: Many flaws in the assumptions.  This handler is called on a thread-pool thread and is entirely disassociated from your main thread.  Setting a boolean doesn't mean much if the main thread isn't checking it or is busy executing code elsewhere.  A boolean is not a synchronization primitive.  That cast is very ugly and probably hiding a declaration error in the callback function.  You have 5 seconds to terminate, if you don't then the OS will force it.  An interlock with the main thread is required, if you don't wait and return from the callback function then it will immediately terminate.

Comment: could you explain a bit more detailed? there are several new concepts I need to investigate from your answer which will take me several hours. For example, how to check the Boolean variable in main thread? or how to force returning to main thread? my purpose is to have a proper clean up of the program objects/data after user clicks [x] close

Comment: actually, after some googling and testing, I have learnt that "return" keyword plays some role here. Some says that normally, "return" will turns back the control to the caller which can be either main thread or the system depending on what is being called. In the case of mine, I've tested by putting "return", I think the case here is my event handler is returning to the system (not the main thread) but it actually does return everytime.

Comment: as you mentioned threadpool, it's interesting to shift to another topic, I think by now understood from your comment. This is inter-thread communication and data sharing. Perhaps following this direction might solve my original problem :)